# Check for "save changes to 'filename' prompt w/ VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

First off, this is not about the saveasfilename dialog box.

Is there a way to have a flag set that checks to see if the "want to save your changes to 'filename.xsls'? dialog box appears during a VBA sub ?

Basically I have a macro that copies some data into another file, displays a MsgBox then closes the file and Excel SHOULD prompt the user to confirm that the file is saved. However, I have a legacy program that locks that file sometimes, causing the prompt to not appear, and it looks like the file was saved but actually wasn't. To 'fix' it I have to close all instances of Excel and the program and start over. It doesn't happen often, but you can miss it if you aren't paying attention or someone less experienced in the process doesn't know to check to make SURE they are prompted to save.

What I'd like to know is if there's a way to have some sort of check / flag value, 1/0, true/false, etc to make sure that dialog box appears. If it doesn't then warn the user that they need to restart Excel and the other program. Basically I'm trying to catch an error that should never happen, so this might be unsolvable.

This is the dialog box I'm referring to:

[image: Excel save changes dialog]

Sometimes it doesn't appear because the file is locked and the VBA sub just continues on.

Comment: If the sub has `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` then it will suppress any such message box.

Comment: I don't have any of that type of code. That dialog box should ALWAYS appear, and it does except for the rare instance the legacy program locks the file. The code is just "ExportDestFile.Close"

Comment: Is there a reason you are simply closing the file and not using `Workbook.Save` or `Workbook.SaveAs`? Or at least passing true into `Workbook.Close`?  For example, `Workbook.Close True` will save changes then close the workbook. IMHO it is best to be as explicit as possible.

Comment: The reason is that the code just copies some data from a main file to an export file and closes it, but the person doing the process needs to visually look to see if it actually copied anything. I have some code right before the close that counts the nubmer of rows in each and shows the count in a message box, but all that is irrelevant because the problem is not with the sub or Excel, but a third party legacy application locking the file. I think people think this is an Excel/code issue, but  all I need to do is hopefully check if there's a way to see if that dialog box appears or not.

Comment: Soulfire I see what you're saying and that does sound like a better way of doing it, but it won't matter because the file is locked and it won't save no matter the method of VBA "saves"

Answer (score 0):

It would probably better to solve the other problem, but since you don't have posted it, we don't know it.
Anyway, everything you want is described here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213428

You can bascally do this:

```
Sub Auto_Close()
If ThisWorkbook.Saved = False Then
    'ThisWorkbook.Save   this would autosave
     Application.GetSaveAsFilename   'this displays the save as dialog
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The first sentence of the post says that it is not about the `GetSaveAsFilename` box.

Comment: I see how this might help, but it probably won't matter because the file won't save - I'm not sure how it would handle a locked file, but I can experiment later. I see where you're thinking.

Comment: @Soulfire The important part here is `If ThisWorkbook.Saved` which is exactly (I think) what the OP needed.

Comment: I would also add `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` which is probably set to false thus suppressing the save warning.

Comment: D_Bester, it's not set to false, 99% of the time the save warning appears, but in some freak instance the legacy app locks the file and the VBA sub continues on thinking it saved. Maybe a better way to do this would be to check the save date, AND byte count before and after the VBA sub runs.

Comment: @purplefolder You say it's set to false but are you sure the legacy program didn't do it? Also it's not clear what you mean by "locks the file"; can you clarify? Does that mean you can't save?

Comment: How about I pose this question (or do I ahve to start a new thread) - how do I check the last date saved, AND byte count before and after the sub runs on the export file? That way I can have Excel show a message box that warns the user the file actually wasn't saved.

Comment: Just check the value of `ThisWorkbook.Saved`; that should do it.

Comment: And yes, checking the date saved and byte count would be a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this as a work around and it's not truly a solution to my question although I suspect there's got to be a way to do it through window classes checking or something. Thank you to everyone who took their time to chime in and offer their brainpower :)

I declared two variables for the file size before and after the sub runs. If the file sizes are equal, then a msgbox appears and says the file may have not been written correctly, or you are overwriting the existing file.

```
Dim ExportFileByte As Long 
Dim ExportBytePostFile As Long

ExportFileByte = FileLen(ExportSourcePath)
```

' (sub runs here and exports a copy of some data to an .XLS file)

```
ExportBytePostFile = FileLen(ExportSourcePath)
If ExportFileByte = ExportBytePostFile Then MsgBox ("Error: File may have not have saved, or file is being overwritten without changes (OK)")
```